# Android Time Picker Example with Platform Version of the DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Google has a Time/Date Picker example found at the link hereafter:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#TimePicker

Meanwhile, this Page states the following towards the beginning of the Article:
“Note: The code samples below show how to create dialogs for a time picker and date picker using the support library APIs for DialogFragment. If your app's minSdkVersion is 11 or higher, you can instead use the platform version of DialogFragment.”

It appears that most examples online using the DialogFragment are referring to this example and are using this Support Library API for the DialogFragment. Would anyone know of any Time Picker example which uses the Platform Version of the DialogFragment instead of the Support Library one?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply import the [platform](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) version of the DialogFragment instead of importing the [support library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html) version. Rest of the code should remain the same as mentioned in [Pickers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#TimePicker).

Simply import `android.app.DialogFragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`.

Since both the classes have same constants, constructor and methods it should work just fine.